# Como escrever uma string em uma imagem ou PDF?

Tags: c#, xaml

Ter uma imagem de template ou um arquivo PDF com uma imagem template embutida nele, a imagem poderia ser um cartão por exemplo, daí na aplicação ter campos `TextBox` como "Nome, CPF e Comentário", daí definir locais na imagem ou documento para se escrever essas strings do `TextBox`, assim preenchendo o cartão com o conteúdo informado

**Exemplo:**

Na aplicação o cara escreve:

*Nome:* Jóse da Rabina

*CPF:* 12345678901

*Comentário:* Este é um comentário

E no PDF ou Imagem aparecer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurei sobre o assunto e não encontrei quase nada, de código só tenho os `textBox` mesmo, se alguém me der uma dica de como fazer ou algo parecido já agradeço.

Comment: Você está fazendo uma aplicação WEB ou DESKTOP?

Comment: É uma aplicação mobile (para Windows Phone), mas os comandos são praticamente os mesmo que os usados em aplicações Windows Form (só mudam as bibliotecas e alguns recursos).